# What are the best practices to create UAT pack in Scrum?

Tags: scrum, agile, user-stories

How do we create test packs for the final UAT. We create user stories and associated acceptance criteria which either can pass or fail. This can be done with test team but for business users what would be the format of the test package?

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the acceptance criteria, I recommend adding "how-to-demo" descriptions to associated User Stories.
The Product Owner should know how to delight the business people.

Answer (score 0):

You want to give guidance to the UAT testers, but not restict them too much. Real users may try things that the developers and testers don't try, so can reveal unexpected bugs.

I would suggest something like the following as a UAT pack:

- A list of the new functionality in the release
- A list of any known issues
- A test script that takes them through the new functionality

But don't forget to encourage the users to look beyond the test script and try things for themselves.

One thing to note is that Scrum does not encourage a 'final UAT'. The preferred approach would be to UAT within each sprint. This can be a challenge to organise, but is worth it as the team's definition of done can include releasable code.